# libGLESv2.dll cannot be found while compiling code that uses OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am trying to learn about using OpenGL with the 4th edition of OpenGL Super Bible, but whenever I try to copy one of the example codes in Visual Studio 2010, I get a **"Open_GL.exe -System Error: The program can't start because libGLESv2.dll is missing from your computer".**
I do have this .dll somewhere on my computer, but don't know how to make it available towards VS. The pre-built binaries on the site do work however.

The code I used, for reference:

```
// Block.cpp
// OpenGL SuperBible, Chapter 1
// Demonstrates an assortment of basic 3D concepts
// Program by Richard S. Wright Jr.

#include "../../shared/gltools.h"   // OpenGL toolkit
#include "../../shared/math3d.h"
#include <math.h>

// Keep track of effects step
int nStep = 0;


// Lighting data
GLfloat lightAmbient[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
GLfloat lightDiffuse[] = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
GLfloat lightSpecular[] = { 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f };
GLfloat materialColor[] = { 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
GLfloat vLightPos[] = { -80.0f, 120.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f };
GLfloat ground[3][3] = { { 0.0f, -25.0f, 0.0f },
                    { 10.0f, -25.0f, 0.0f },
                    { 10.0f, -25.0f, -10.0f } };

GLuint textures[4];





// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
M3DMatrix44f mCubeTransform;
M3DVector4f pPlane;


// Clear the window with current clearing color
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

glPushMatrix();

// Draw plane that the cube rests on
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
if(nStep == 5)
    {
    glColor3ub(255,255,255);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, -25.3f, -100.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, -25.3f, 100.0f);        
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(100.0f,  -25.3f, 100.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(100.0f,  -25.3f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();
    }
else
    {
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.90f); // Blue
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, -25.3f, -100.0f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0f, -25.3f, 100.0f);        
        glVertex3f(100.0f,  -25.3f, 100.0f);
        glVertex3f(100.0f,  -25.3f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();
    }


// Set drawing color to Red
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// Enable, disable lighting
if(nStep > 2)
    {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,lightSpecular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, materialColor);
    glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS,128);
    }

// Move the cube slightly forward and to the left
glTranslatef(-10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

switch(nStep)
    {
    // Just draw the wire framed cube
    case 0:
        glutWireCube(50.0f);
        break;

    // Same wire cube with hidden line removal simulated
    case 1:
        // Front Face (before rotation)
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);

            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);

            glVertex3f(-25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);

            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
        glEnd();

        // Top of cube
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            // Front Face
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);

            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);

            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);

            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
        glEnd();

        // Last two segments for effect
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,-25.0f);

            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,-25.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);
        glEnd();

        break;

    // Uniform colored surface, looks 2D and goofey
    case 2:
        glutSolidCube(50.0f);
        break;

    case 3:
        glutSolidCube(50.0f);
        break;

    // Draw a shadow with some lighting
    case 4:
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mCubeTransform);
        glutSolidCube(50.0f);
        glPopMatrix();

        // Disable lighting, we'll just draw the shadow as black
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

        glPushMatrix();

        m3dGetPlaneEquation(pPlane, ground[0], ground[1], ground[2]);
        m3dMakePlanarShadowMatrix(mCubeTransform, pPlane, vLightPos);
        //MakeShadowMatrix(ground, lightpos, cubeXform);
        glMultMatrixf(mCubeTransform);

        glTranslatef(-10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);          

        // Set drawing color to Black
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glutSolidCube(50.0f);
        break;

    case 5:
        glColor3ub(255,255,255);
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mCubeTransform);

        // Front Face (before rotation)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
        glEnd();

        // Top of cube
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Front Face
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
        glEnd();

        // Last two segments for effect
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[3]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,-25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,-25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,-25.0f,25.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(25.0f,25.0f,25.0f);
        glEnd();


        glPopMatrix();

        // Disable lighting, we'll just draw the shadow as black
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glPushMatrix();

        m3dGetPlaneEquation(pPlane, ground[0], ground[1], ground[2]);
        m3dMakePlanarShadowMatrix(mCubeTransform, pPlane, vLightPos);
        glMultMatrixf(mCubeTransform);          

        glTranslatef(-10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);          

        // Set drawing color to Black
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glutSolidCube(50.0f);
        break;

    }

glPopMatrix();

// Flush drawing commands
glutSwapBuffers();
}

// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering
// context. 
void SetupRC()
{
    GLbyte *pBytes;
    GLint nWidth, nHeight, nComponents;
    GLenum format;

// Black background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glGenTextures(4, textures);

// Load the texture objects
    pBytes = gltLoadTGA("floor.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
free(pBytes);

pBytes = gltLoadTGA("Block4.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
free(pBytes);

pBytes = gltLoadTGA("block5.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
free(pBytes);

pBytes = gltLoadTGA("block6.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[3]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
free(pBytes);
    }

void KeyPressFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
if(key == 32)
    {
    nStep++;

    if(nStep > 5)
        nStep = 0;
    }

// Refresh the Window
glutPostRedisplay();
}


void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
// Calculate new clipping volume
GLfloat windowWidth;
GLfloat windowHeight;

// Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
// (you cant make a window of zero width).
if(h == 0)
    h = 1;

// Keep the square square
if (w <= h) 
    {
    windowHeight = 100.0f*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w;
    windowWidth = 100.0f;
    }
else 
    {
    windowWidth = 100.0f*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h;
    windowHeight = 100.0f;
    }

    // Set the viewport to be the entire window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

// Set the clipping volume
glOrtho(-100.0f, windowWidth, -100.0f, windowHeight, -200.0f, 200.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION, vLightPos);

glRotatef(30.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(330.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
glutCreateWindow("3D Effects Demo");
glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPressFunc);
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

SetupRC();

glutMainLoop();
glDeleteTextures(4,textures);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do have this .dll somewhere on my computer

`libGLESv2.dll` sounds suspiciously like an implementation of OpenGL *ES 2.0*. Which will not execute your code, since your code is written for desktop OpenGL.

In short, you are linking to the wrong library. On Windows, you should be linking to `OpenGL32.lib`.

Comment: Ah, Thank you. I'll be looking for that library instead, than!

Comment: Using OpenGL32.lib fixed the problem. Thanks again

Comment: libglesv2.dll is from https://github.com/google/angle project